# How to replace values in a specific column

Tags: r

I have a big data frame from a survey. There is some statements where I need to use revere coding, hence I need to change values in few columns. I have tried below code (where x represents the column where I want to make the changes)

```
df$x <- replace( df$x, 1=7, 2=6, 3=5, 5=3, 6=2, 7=1)
```

But this did not work. Every help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your column has only 1-7 values you can subtract those values from 8 to reverse the values.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(7, 10, replace = TRUE))
df$y <- 8 - df$x
#Or maybe more general
#df$y <- max(df$x) + 1 - df$x
df

#   x y
#1  7 1
#2  7 1
#3  3 5
#4  6 2
#5  3 5
#6  2 6
#7  2 6
#8  6 2
#9  3 5
#10 5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can replace values is using `which`:

```
df$x[which(df$x=1)] <- 7 # this replaces 1 with 7
```

Another way is to use `ifelse`:

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$x == 1,7,ifelse(df$x == 2,6,ifelse....)) # replaces 1 with 7, 2 with 6 and so on..
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `case_when` from package `dplyr`. The syntax is very clean.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(x=case_when(
  x == 1 ~ 7,
  x == 2 ~ 6,
  x == 3 ~ 5,
  x == 6 ~ 2,
  x == 7 ~ 1,
  TRUE ~ as.numeric(x)
))
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(7, 10, replace = TRUE))
df
```

The solution above overwrites the varaible `x`. To compare result, I created a `new_x` variable with the replaced data:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new_x=case_when(
  x == 1 ~ 7,
  x == 2 ~ 6,
  x == 3 ~ 5,
  x == 6 ~ 2,
  x == 7 ~ 1,
  TRUE ~ as.numeric(x)
))

   x new_x
1  1     7
2  4     4
3  7     1
4  1     7
5  2     6
6  5     5
7  7     1
8  3     5
9  6     2
10 2     6
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `which.max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(y = x[which.max(x)] - x + 1)
```